# O output print não está sendo exibido

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Digitei exatamente isso:

```
import math
num = float(input('Digite um numero: '))
print('A parte inteira do numero {} é {}.'.format(num, math.trunc(num)))
```

Porém, ao executar, só aparece isso:

```
Digite um numero: 9.8

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Gostaria de saber por que não consigo exibir o que digitei na terceira linha.

Comment: No [repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/CandidScentedModules) funciona como esperado. Como fez para executar o programa?

Comment: Eu estava usando Shift + F10. Tentei Ctrl + Shift + F10 e funcionou. Caso seja necessário apagar a pergunta é só me avisar. Obrigado.

Comment: @JoãoDeiro, como descobriu o problema, sugiro responder sua própria pergunta explicando como resolveu.

Comment: @Dherik como assim? ainda não sei usar o site muito bem.

Comment: @JoãoDeiro Acredito que apareça para você, aqui embaixo da pergunta, uma caixa de texto com o título "Sua resposta". Coloque lá como resolveu seu problema (o conteúdo do seu comentário e mais algo que deseja adicionar) e clique no botão "Publique sua resposta".

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. Antes eu estava dando "run" pelo comando Shift + F10. Tentei pelo comando Ctrl + Shift + F10 e consegui resolver o problema.